# Install of ECM ECS community edition - Failed taskTASK [common_baseline_install : Common | Format ECS partition(s)]

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, emc

I am trying to get emc ecs community software installed as a standalone all in one node deployment on ec2. I am seeing the following error . Any help will be much appreciated.

failed: [172.31.40.131] (item=/dev/nvme2n1) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "/dev/nvme2n1", "msg": "Device **/dev/nvme2n11** not found."}

failed: [172.31.40.131] (item=/dev/nvme1n1) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "/dev/nvme1n1", "msg": "Device **/dev/nvme1n11** not found."}

Output of :

    lsblk

        NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

        nvme0n1     259:1    0   30G  0 disk
        └─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   30G  0 part /

        nvme1n1     259:0    0  120G  0 disk
        └─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0  120G  0 part
        nvme2n1     259:4    0  108G  0 disk
        └─nvme2n1p1 259:3    0  108G  0 part
[root@luna log]#

Snippet of the log

Jan 10 14:35:29 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: TASK [common_baseline_install : Common | Create GPT partition table(s) on ECS block device(s)] **********************************************************************************************#015

Jan 10 14:35:29 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme2n1 mklabel gpt removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None


Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 kernel: nvme2n1:

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme2n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme1n1 mklabel gpt removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 kernel: nvme1n1:

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme1n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: TASK [common_baseline_install : Common | Partition ECS block device(s)] *********************************************************************************************************************#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme2n1 mkpart xfs 0% 100% removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme2n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme1n1 mkpart xfs 0% 100% removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme1n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: TASK [common_baseline_install : Common | Check alignment of ECS partitions(s)] **************************************************************************************************************#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme2n1 align-check opt 1 removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 kernel: nvme2n1: p1

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme2n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=False _raw_params=/sbin/parted -s /dev/nvme1n1 align-check opt 1 removes=None creates=None chdir=None stdin=None

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 kernel: nvme1n1: p1

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;36mchanged: [172.31.40.131] => (item=/dev/nvme1n1)#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #015

Jan 10 14:35:30 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: TASK [common_baseline_install : Common | Format ECS partition(s)] ***************************************************************************************************************************#015

Jan 10 14:35:31 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-filesystem: Invoked with resizefs=False force=True opts=None dev=/dev/nvme2n11 fstype=xfs

Jan 10 14:35:31 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;31mfailed: [172.31.40.131] (item=/dev/nvme2n1) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "/dev/nvme2n1", "msg": "Device /dev/nvme2n11 not found."}#033[0m#015

Jan 10 14:35:31 ip-172-31-40-131 ansible-filesystem: Invoked with resizefs=False force=True opts=None dev=/dev/nvme1n11 fstype=xfs

Jan 10 14:35:31 ip-172-31-40-131 journal: #033[1;31mfailed: [172.31.40.131] (item=/dev/nvme1n1) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "/dev/nvme1n1", "msg": "Device /dev/nvme1n11 not found."}#033[0m#015

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help you further without code or the data it is being fed by, but the problem appears to be that in your `filesystem` tasks, you are not correctly building the partition device name:

```
/dev/nvme1n11
```

should be:

```
/dev/nvme1n1p1
```

I am guessing you have a typo in the code you are using to build the dev string. If that does not help, add the code you are using in your `filesystem` task, together with any data you are feeding it via a loop to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When using newer nitro instance types in ec2, the EMC-ECS community edition code does not seem to be handle the task of format ecs partition .This can be solved by using T2 instance type , it is being tracked here
https://github.com/EMCECS/ECS-CommunityEdition/issues/456